# How to convert a flat dataframe into a Tuple2<S,T> typed Dataset in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, join, dataframe, nested, dataset

I am using Spark 2.0

I have a dataframe joined from two dataframes,   which are  converted from `JavaRDD<ORD>, and JavaRDD<Buddy>` respectively, using Encoder.

```
The schema of Dataset<Row> converted from JavaRDD<ORD> is schema1 :
root
|-- buddyPathAverageSignalList: array (nullable = true)
|       |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|       |       |-- averageSignal: float (nullable = false)
|       |       |-- buddyId: integer (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- repId: integer (nullable = false)



The schema of Dataset<Row> converted from JavaRDD<Buddy> is schema2:
root
|-- buddyId: integer (nullable = false)
|-- buddyToTgbSignal: float (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- ordId: integer (nullable = false)
|-- ordToBuddySignal: float (nullable = true)
|-- ringStep: integer (nullable = false)

The schema of the joined dataframe is schema3, it is flat
root
|-- buddyId: integer (nullable = false)
|-- buddyToTgbSignal: float (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- ordId: integer (nullable = false)
|-- ordToBuddySignal: float (nullable = true)
|-- ringStep: integer (nullable = false)
|-- buddyPathAverageSignalList: array (nullable = true)
|       |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|       |       |-- averageSignal: float (nullable = false)
|       |       |-- buddyId: integer (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- repId: integer (nullable = false)
```

Now I want to convert the above joined flat dataframe (with schema3) into  `JavaRDD<Tuple2<ORD, Buddy>>` or `Dataset<Tuple2<ORD, Buddy>>`

I cannot find a good way to do that. I am hoping to use Encoder of class ORD, Buddy or/and that of Tuple2 so that I do not need to parse each field one by one, but I was not successful.

The `Dataset<Tuple2<ORDType, BuddyType>>` has a schema of the following nested form:

```
scheme of Dataset<Tuple2<ORDType, BuddyType>> scheme4 

root
|-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
|       |-- buddyPathAverageSignalList: array (nullable = true)
|       |       |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
|       |       |       |-- averageSignal: float (nullable = true)
|       |       |       |-- buddyId: integer (nullable = true)
|       |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|       |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|       |-- repId: integer (nullable = true)
|-- _2: struct (nullable = false)
|       |-- buddyId: integer (nullable = true)
|       |-- buddyToTgbSignal: float (nullable = true)
|       |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|       |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|       |-- ordId: integer (nullable = true)
|       |-- ordToBuddySignal: float (nullable = true)
|       |-- ringStep: integer (nullable = true)
```

Is there a way to convert the joined flat dataframe with schema3 into nested schema4, so that I can then converted it into `Dataset<Tuple2<ORD, Buddy>>` ?

Any other suggestions? I know I can just use Dataset to do the join with Dataset directly, but I want to tested the Dataframe, i.e. the `Dataset<Row>` way, since it is claimed that the performance is better.

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe is just a Dataset[Row] in Spark 2.0. As Dataframes are using same execution engine as Datasets their performance should be the same.

What's related to your question - I can't find what's a join key in your example. Is it latitude/longitue? If so, you should be able to use `data1.joinWith(data2, data1("latitude") === data2("latitude") && data1("longitude") === data2("longitude"))` (not sure about exact syntax)